# any idea when the Moleculer TCP transport will graduate from experimental?

Tags: moleculer

I see in git that the Moleculer TCP transport is about 4 months old, and is still flagged as experimental.  Any idea when this may be production ready ?

Comment: Add code or explain more you question

Answer (score 2):

I'm waiting for feedbacks regarding TCP transporter stability from users who are using because I have not tested it thoroughly yet. So I will flag it to stable when somebody confirms that it's working properly or I can test it in a production environment.

Comment: Is there any example app available for moleculer transporters?